# Error in stat_smooth when plotting power regression with select points

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I am trying to plot a power regression line in the formula y ~ a*x^b using ggplot in R. 
It looks like I need to use the method = "nls" under `stat_smooth` but am getting a warning message that missing or infinity values are produced when evaluating the model.

I can get it to work if I exclude some points from my data, but I can't see any difference between those points and the ones that work
What is going on here?

Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mydf <- structure(list(x = c(3.09090909090909, 1.09677419354839, 1.47826086956522, 
                             2.125, 5.23076923076923, 2.42857142857143, 45.3333333333333, 
                             2.3448275862069, 2.51851851851852, 45.3333333333333, 6.18181818181818, 
                             1.78947368421053, 9.71428571428572, 13.6, 2.95652173913043, 4, 
                             11.3333333333333, 1.51111111111111, 3.23809523809524, 6.8, 22.6666666666667, 
                             5.66666666666667, 1.83783783783784, 2.61538461538462, 1.30769230769231, 
                             1.7, 7.55555555555556, 1.03030303030303, 2, 1.88888888888889, 
                             1.17241379310345, 1.13333333333333, 1.4468085106383, 8.5, 2.26666666666667, 
                             1.01492537313433, 1.61904761904762, 3.57894736842105, 4.68965517241379, 
                             2.19354838709677, 3.77777777777778, 17, 4.25, 1.07936507936508, 
                             1.33333333333333, 1.74358974358974, 1.28301886792453, 2.06060606060606, 
                             4.68965517241379, 1.94285714285714, 2.83333333333333, 1.04615384615385, 
                             2.72, 1.58139534883721, 1.23636363636364, 1.41666666666667, 1.65853658536585, 
                             1.15254237288136, 1.11475409836066, 1.38775510204082, 1.0625, 
                             1.36, 3.4, 1.19298245614035, 1.21428571428571, 1.25925925925926, 
                             1.54545454545455), y = c(193.571428571429, 289, 249, 215.285714285714, 
                                                      179.857142857143, 204, 141.142857142857, 206.142857142857, 201.428571428571, 
                                                      141.142857142857, 178.285714285714, 224.714285714286, 165.714285714286, 
                                                      160, 198.428571428571, 184.857142857143, 164.285714285714, 245.857142857143, 
                                                      192.714285714286, 172, 150.714285714286, 179.142857142857, 223.571428571429, 
                                                      200.714285714286, 259.285714285714, 230, 171.714285714286, 315.714285714286, 
                                                      216, 220.571428571429, 277, 285, 250, 170.285714285714, 209.142857142857, 
                                                      335.714285714286, 238.285714285714, 188.571428571429, 181.142857142857, 
                                                      210.857142857143, 185.714285714286, 151.142857142857, 181.428571428571, 
                                                      295.857142857143, 257.142857142857, 225.857142857143, 261.714285714286, 
                                                      215.714285714286, 181.142857142857, 217.857142857143, 199.714285714286, 
                                                      313.571428571429, 200.428571428571, 242.857142857143, 269.714285714286, 
                                                      250.142857142857, 234.857142857143, 282, 285.142857142857, 253.285714285714, 
                                                      309.857142857143, 253.857142857143, 189.142857142857, 274.714285714286, 
                                                      273.285714285714, 261.857142857143, 244.142857142857)), row.names = c(NA, -67), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
mydf %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+ 
      geom_point()+ 
      stat_smooth(
            method = "nls",
            formula = "y~a*x^b",
            method.args = list(start= c(a = 1,b=1)),
            se=FALSE
      )
# Warning message:
#       Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
#       Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

[image]
It works if I exclude selected points:

```
mydf_trunc <- mydf[c(1:51, 53:58, 60, 63, 67),]

mydf_trunc%>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+ 
      geom_point()+ 
      stat_smooth(
            method = "nls",
            formula = "y~a*x^b",
            method.args = list(start= c(a = 1,b=1)),
            se=FALSE
      )
```

[image]
But I can't see any difference between the points that work and the ones that cause problems.  In this figure the red points are the ones that cause the stat_smooth to fail

```
bad_pts <- mydf[c(52,59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66),]
bad_pts     
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
# x     y
# <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1.05  314.
# 2  1.11  285.
# 3  1.06  310.
# 4  1.36  254.
# 5  1.19  275.
# 6  1.21  273.
# 7  1.26  262.
```

[image]
The warning message says that these points are causing missing or infite values, but they appear to fit along the same curve as the rest of the points, and there aren't any missing values.

Comment: I'm not an expert on nls, but your code will work with the full dataset if you specified starting estimates that are closer to the optimum. See suggested approach [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183776/174215). Based on this approach, `start = c(a = 270, b = -0.22)` will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that a) the offending points are duplicates of some of the other points at least for their x values and thus giving you infinite slope in parts of the estimation process, and that b) the asymptote should be allowed to be above zero:

```
ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x = jitter(x), y = y))+ 
    geom_point()+ 
    geom_smooth(
        method="nls",
        formula= y~ a*x^(-b) +cc,
        method.args = list(start= c(a = 1,b=2 ,cc=100)),
        se=FALSE
    )
```

[image]

Comment: This works, and it appears as if several things are going on. It is definitely sensitive to start values. Adding the additional term to allow the asymptote to be different than zero allows for a much better fit.  I do have 2 sets of duplicate points (x= 4.68, y = 181; and x = 45.3 and y = 141) but they don't seem to be causing the stat_smooth to fail, and  different start values work with and without the "cc" term as well as depending on if the x scale is displayed as log or not.

Comment: I didn't think that duplicate points (with identical x and y values) would be a problem. I thought that non-identical ponts with same x but different Y's might be. Also think that x values that were `all.equal` might cause problems, too. That was my _guess_ as to what might be causing infinite slope estimates.